# Reshaping tensor after max pooling ValueError: Shapes are not compatible

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, reshape, convolution

I am building CNN fitting my own data, based on [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_character_cnn.py)

Basically, my data has 3640 features; I have a convolution layer followed by a pooling layer, that pools every other feature, so I end up with dimensions (?, 1, 1819, 1) because 3638 features after conv layer / 2 == 1819.

When I try to reshape my data after pooling to get it in the form [n_samples, n_fetures]

```
    print("pool_shape", pool_shape) #pool  (?, 1, 1819, 10)
    print("y_shape", y_shape) #y  (?,)

    pool.set_shape([pool_shape[0], pool_shape[2]*pool_shape[3]])
    y.set_shape([y_shape[0], 1])
```

I get an error:

**`ValueError: Shapes (?, 1, 1819, 10) and (?, 18190) are not compatible`**

My code:

```
N_FEATURES = 140*26
N_FILTERS = 1
WINDOW_SIZE = 3

def my_conv_model(x, y):

    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    print("x ", x.get_shape())
    print("y ", y.get_shape())

    # to form a 4d tensor of shape batch_size x 1 x N_FEATURES x 1
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1, N_FEATURES, 1])
    # this will give you sliding window of 1 x WINDOW_SIZE convolution.
    features = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs=x,
                                               num_outputs=N_FILTERS,
                                               kernel_size=[1, WINDOW_SIZE],
                                               padding='VALID')

    print("features ", features.get_shape()) #features  (?, 1, 3638, 10)

    # Max pooling across output of Convolution+Relu.
    pool = tf.nn.max_pool(features, ksize=[1, 1, 2, 1],
                             strides=[1, 1, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

    pool_shape = pool.get_shape()
    y_shape = y.get_shape()
    print("pool_shape", pool_shape) #pool  (?, 1, 1819, 10)
    print("y_shape", y_shape) #y  (?,)

### here comes the error ###
    pool.set_shape([pool_shape[0], pool_shape[2]*pool_shape[3]])
    y.set_shape([y_shape[0], 1])

    pool_shape = pool.get_shape()
    y_shape = y.get_shape()
    print("pool_shape", pool_shape) #pool  (?, 1, 1819, 10)
    print("y_shape", y_shape) #y  (?,)

    prediction, loss = learn.models.logistic_regression(pool, y)
    return prediction, loss
```

**How to reshape the data to get any meaningful representation of it and to later pass it to logistic regression layer?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a confusion between the [`Tensor.set_shape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor.set_shape) method and the [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) operator. In this case, you should use `tf.reshape()` because you are changing the shape of the `pool` and `y` tensors:

- The `tf.reshape(tensor, shape)` operator takes a `tensor` of any shape, and returns a tensor with the given `shape`, as long as they have the same number of elements. This operator should be used to **change** the shape of the input tensor.
- The `tensor.set_shape(shape)` method takes a `tensor` that might have a partially known or unknown shape, and asserts to TensorFlow that it actually has the given `shape`. This method should be used to **provide more information about** the shape of a particular tensor.

  It can be used, e.g., when you take the output of an operator that has a data-dependent output shape (such as [`tf.image.decode_jpeg()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/image.html#decode_jpeg)) and assert that it has a static shape (e.g. based on knowledge about the sizes of images in your dataset).

In your program, you should replace the calls to `set_shape()` with something like the following:

```
pool_shape = tf.shape(pool)
pool = tf.reshape(pool, [pool_shape[0], pool_shape[2] * pool_shape[3]])

y_shape = tf.shape(y)
y = tf.reshape(y, [y_shape[0], 1])

# Or, more straightforwardly:
y = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
```

Comment: when I do `pool = tf.reshape(pool, [pool_shape[0], pool_shape[2]*pool_shape[3]])`, I get: `TypeError: Expected int32, got Dimension(None) of type 'Dimension' instead.`. I suspect this is because pool shape is `pool_shape == (?, 1, 1819, 10)` where the very first argument needs to be inferred, and is not explicit integer. How do I work around this issue? The inferred parameter is a batch size that could vary, I guess.

Comment: Also, at the very beginning: `def my_conv_model(x, y):

    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)

    print("x ", x.get_shape())
    print("y ", y.get_shape())` the shapes printed are `x  (?, 3640)` and 
`y  (?,)`. Is there a way to actually get the dimension and store them in a variable or something?

Comment: Ah, I updated the answer to use `tf.shape()` (which uses the actual run-time shape) instead of `Tensor.get_shape()`. It looks like the batch size is variable in your program. If you want to see the actual shape of a tensor whose size can vary, you can pass the tensor to a `tf.shape()` op and pass the result to `sess.run()`.

Comment: I later get an error `ValueError: Shape of a new variable (logistic_regression/weights) must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 1).` any ideas what could possibly go wrong? Here is the code: https://github.com/Oleksandra28/Research/blob/master/step_4_cnn_4.py